# useConvexPolyhedron collision on react-three/cannon clipping through object

Tags: reactjs, blender, react-three-fiber, cannon.js, react-three-drei

I am having issues trying to make collision work properly with an imported glb file only used for collision.

There are two parts to this question:

1. I am currently getting a whole lot of faceNormal errors and vertices warnings in the console.

```
.faceNormals[767] = Vec3(0.999994684003945,-4.252105447140875e-10,0.003260669233505899) looks like it points into the shape? The vertices follow. Make sure they are ordered CCW around the normal, using the right hand rule.
```

```
.vertices[555] = Vec3(-18.135730743408203,9.071623802185059,-13.433568000793457)
```

I am not sure if this error has something to do with how I'm merging the geometry of the object or how the object is built inside blender.

2. When my sphere collides with the glb model it will clip through it sometimes with enough force. (holding down the W key to move the sphere forward). It clips through especially on the edges of the environment, against a flat wall it gives some resistance but still manages to clip through with enough time holding down a movement key.

Here is the code I'm using to import my glb model:

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import { useConvexPolyhedron } from "@react-three/cannon";
import { Geometry } from "three-stdlib/deprecated/Geometry";
import {useGLTF} from "@react-three/drei";
import collision from "./Collision6.glb";

function toConvexProps(bufferGeometry) {
  const geo = new Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(bufferGeometry);

  geo.mergeVertices();
  return [geo.vertices.map((v) => [v.x, v.y, v.z]), geo.faces.map((f) => [f.a, f.b, f.c]), []];
}

export default function Collision(props) {

  const { nodes } = useGLTF(collision);
  const geo = useMemo(() => toConvexProps(nodes.Collision001.geometry), [nodes]);
  const [ref] = useConvexPolyhedron(() => ({ type: 'Static', mass: 100 ,position:[0,0,0], args: geo
  }));
  return (
    <mesh
      ref={ref}
      geometry={nodes.Collision001.geometry}
    >
      <meshStandardMaterial wireframe color="#ff0000" opacity={0} transparent />
    </mesh>
  );
}
```